# automysqlbackup max size .sql.gz

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, backup

Are there a size limit when saving a BDD in .sql.gz? A zip is generated but is 4KB while my BDD actually 250MB ...
Unable to open the zip.
My script works because other BDD are saved!
Any idea ?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Could you clarify your definition of BDD? I dont think you mean Behaviour-Driven Develiopment.

Comment: Yes, this is my database mysql, sorry.

Comment: Thomas, have you got any idea ?